# How to overload methods in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

My current Android application employs Kotlin & Room

I have a `BaseDAO` interface as follows:-

```
interface BaseDAO<T> {

    /**
     * Insert an object in the database.
     *
     * @param obj the object to be inserted.
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(obj: T) : Long

    /**
     * Insert multiple objects in the database.
     *
     * @param obj the objects to be inserted.
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(obj: List<T>) : List<Long>

    /**
     * Update an object from the database.
     *
     * @param obj the object to be updated
     */
    @Update
    fun update(obj: T)

    /**
     * Delete an object from the database
     *
     * @param obj the object to be deleted
     */
    @Delete
    fun delete(obj: T)
}
```

I would also like to have an insert method that accepts a single instance of a DO like this in my specific DAO interface

```
@Dao
interface SingleDAO : BaseDAO<SingleDO> {

    @Query("SELECT count(*) from single limit 1")
    fun count(): Long

    /**
     * Insert single object in the database.
     *
     * @param obj the object to be inserted.
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(obj: SingleDO) : Long
}
```

Android Studio reports this compile error

```
'insert' hides member of supertype 'BaseDAO' and needs 'override' modifier
```

I want to Overload not override `'insert'` method

If I try and add `'@JvmOverloads'` to my overloading `insert` method Android Studio gives me this error

```
`'@JvmOverloads'` annotation cannot be used on interface methods
```

How can I overload my BaseDAO method?

Comment: `@JvmOverloads` on a method with parameters without default values does nothing.
Are you sure that those 2 methods clash? They have different signature. Maybe you have another method in `BaseDAO`?

Comment: they definitely clash... i get 'insert' hides member of supertype 'BaseDAO' and needs 'override' modifier from Android Studio

Comment: The `fun insert(obj: SingleDO)` is the same as `fun insert(obj: T)` since the `SingleDAO` extends `BaseDAO<SingleDO>`...isn't it?

Comment: @Demigod this is exactly what I meant before author modified the question content. 
@Hector the solution is to add `override` modifier in subclass (`SingleDAO `), but don't call `super.insert()` in subclass implementation if you would like to have a different implementation in a subclass. Otherwise you might think of composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should just remove the `@JvmOverloads` annotation :)

Comment: without the @JvmOverloads i get... 'insert' hides member of supertype 'BaseDAO' and needs 'override' modifier

Comment: I can see that you updated your question - you already have insert method for a single object, why would you need to overload it? It is just the same